# TitanDB: Avoid searching twice to find if node exists

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3

I am trying to check if vertex exists before creating a new one or updating existing one:

```
 x = g.V().has('name','xyz').hasNext()  // /search 1

 if ( x != true ){
    g.V().addVertex( 'name', 'xyz' ) }

 g.V().has('name','xyz').property('x','1')  // search 2
```

The example has 2 searches for element with name = xyz; I would like to save first search to a variable and refer to it later.

However, if I try to save search, it does not get saved:

```
 gremlin> x = g.V().has('name','xyz')
 ==>v[40964336]
 gremlin> x
 gremlin>
```

What is the way to avoid having two searches in this example? - thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you missed `tryNext`:

```
g.V().has('name','xyz').tryNext().orElseGet {
  graph.addVertex('name', 'xyz')
}.property('x', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found my own answer: collect()

```
 x= g.V().has('name','axdas').collect()

 if ( x.size() > 0 ) { //set property
   }

 else { // add vertex
   }
```

Comment: I think what you were looking for was `x = g.V().has('name', 'axdas').next()`